# Parent-child recursive two-way binding in angular 2.0

Tags: angular

I want to create angular component that uses itself recursively to create all kinds of inputs based on jsonschema

You can see full code [here](https://github.com/purpleP/angular2-admin-component)

I know that to create two-way data-binding we can use ngModel, but I don't know how to use it in custom component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also leverage `@Input` and `@Output` as described below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom',
  template: `
    <div>
      {{value}} - <span (click)="updateValue()">Update</span>
    </div>
  `
})
export class CustomComponent {
  @Input()
  value:string;
  @Output()
  valueChange:EventEmitter;

  constructor() {
    this.valueChange = new EventEmitter();
  }

  updateValue() {
    this.valueChange.emit('other value');
  }
}
```

This way the instance you bound to the value of the custom component will leverage two-way binding. When the `updateValue` is called in the custom component, the corresponding property (here `someProperty`) will be also updated in the parent component:

```
@Component({
  (...)
  template: `
    <custom [(value)]="someProperty"></custom>
  `,
  directives: [ CustomComponent ] 
})
export class MyComponent {
  someProperty:string;

  constructor() {
    this.someProperty = 'test';
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ubtMXpGefgybGK4A3Pho?p=preview.

Comment: I think there is to much code for doing such simple thing. Isn't there a better way? To Write a bunch of @Output and updateThis, updateThat methods for every two-way bounded property is far from good, don't you think?

Comment: In fact, I described the way to define two-way binding for components. This works for all object kinds even primitive types. The approach of Angular2 is to define a clear "contract" for components: what they accept as parameters  (input) and what they can fire (output). That said, you can always provide a parameter and work by reference. This allows not to have to define / handle `EventEmitter`s but this doesn't work for primitive types...

Comment: can you provide example of "provide a parameter and work by reference"? Also, I've changed my code, and implemented two-way binding through Input and Output as you've suggested. Now while I can see changes of entity in recursive element I can't see them in AppComponent

Comment: I believe even that you answer doesn't answer my question, because If I'm correct than your suggestion would work only one level deep in template hierarchy.

Comment: Ok, I've managed to create two-way data binding via using $event object everywhere. Thanks!